# What word means "the feeling of discomfort caused by watching people's ineptitude"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am watching a UK TV programme called "The Apprentice".  The candidates have to sell guided tours.  Some candidates are terrible at giving these tours.  They fluff their lines, or they haven't researched, or they make up "facts".

Watching their ineptitude cause a feeling of discomfort.  **What is the best word for this discomfort?**

The German word schadenfreude means roughly "the pleasure derived from the misfortunes of others".  The word I want would be almost an antonym of schadenfreude - "the discomfort derived from the mosfortunes of others".  Except not the misfortunes but the uselessness of others.

Comment: I know well the feeling and I wouldn't mind having a word for it.  However, I don't think that "vicarious embarrassment" quite fits, since (fortunately or not), embarrassment does not always arise from ineptitude.  And "cringeworthy" seems a bit non-specific.

Comment: In Finnish, that would be **myötähäpeä**. It means **second-hand embarrassment**. The feeling of shame and embarrassment because of another person's stupid or embarrassing acts.

Comment: German has an even better word for that, which means EXACTLY what you described: "fremdschämen", to feel ashamed about something *foreign*, i.e. people on TV, drunk friends at a party etc.. Really an interesting question. I don't know any english term getting close to that, without bloating like you did in the question title.

Comment: If you have feelings of *discomfort*, then it is not *Schadenfreude* in German (this would be your being *amused* that a mishap happened to someone else) but rather *fremdschämen*

Comment: The word is "sympathy" if you feel badly for them.

Comment: @PatrickM although the question is similar, it's not the same. The question specifically states that it is not the misfortune of others seen, but their ineptitude/uselessness.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck the accepted answer here is "Vicarious Embarassment." This answer and others overlap both questions. The other question says "I feel embarrassed for them" and poses 2/5 examples which expressly mention embarrassment, and the other 3 examples that would be embarassing to the unfortunate observee *if they were aware* of their situation; a lack of social awareness is a form of ineptitude, often compounding other ineptitude, such as poorly performing a tour (which has high overlap with the first example in the other question). I think it's a dupe by the standards of this site.

Comment: I suggest 'cringe'.

Comment: The phrase "watching the news" comes to mind.

Comment: That other question: "horny" is a valid answer for the other question, but not for this one.

Comment: [Vergüenza ajena](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12350/what-is-the-word-for-the-emotion-i-feel-when-i-see-someone-being-humiliated/97206#97206) in Spanish .

Comment: 'Toe-curling' is also worth a look.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[vicarious embarrassment](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=vicarious%20embarrassment)

> The very uncomfortable sympathetic feeling experienced while you watch someone else embarrassing themselves. This feeling is often intensified when the person embarrassing themself is not aware of how embarrassing their behavior is. In this case it is more like you are feeling the embarrassment on their behalf.

- [The Opposite Of Schadenfreude: Vicarious Embarrassment](http://www.npr.org/2014/07/19/332760081/the-opposite-of-schadenfreude-vicarious-embarrassment)
- [Vicarious Embarrassment: Witnessing Awkward Moments Triggers Pain Centers In The Brain](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/04/15/vicarious-embarrassment-w_n_849719.html)
- [Your Flaws Are My Pain: Linking Empathy To Vicarious Embarrassment](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0018675)
- [Validation and correlates of the vicarious embarrassment scale](http://www.academia.edu/6563886/Validation_and_correlates_of_the_vicarious_embarrassment_scale)

[Facepalm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facepalm) (slang) is another possible translation of the import term (from German) [fremdschämen](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fremdsch%C3%A4men).

> A German term which describes the process of being vicariously embarrassed by someone else. For example when somebody's concept for a great party gag goes terrible wrong and you watch him fail in the middle of all of his friends.
> *Tom was completely wasted while he held the speech on Mike's wedding party. Fremdschämen in perfection.*

urban dictionary

> “Fremdschämen describes the almost-horror you feel when you notice that somebody is oblivious to how embarrassing they truly are,” writes Daniel Hawes in Psychology Today. “Fremdscham [the noun] occurs when someone who should feel embarrassed for themselves simply is not, and you start feeling embarrassment in their place.”
>
> ... **the auditions for American Idol and all of the related rip-offs are Fremdschämen factories,**

http://www.nationalreview.com/article/369402/how-do-you-solve-problem-wendy-jonah-goldberg

[image: Picard facepalm]

---

Alo's suggestion of 'cringeworthy' is also very valid.

More generally, here in the UK we sometimes talk about 'car crash' or 'train crash' TV. In the US they call it a "train wreck".

Comment: I hear/say the phrase "embarrassment transfer" occasionally. It's half-serious but it gets the point across.

Comment: Someone on reddit I think once came up with a great translation for "fremdschämen": strangershame.

Answer (score 50):

I quite like **cringeworthy** to describe this.

I feel it on a weekly basis watching The Apprentice but keep coming back for more!

For example "James singing nursery rhymes on the coach was so cringeworthy".

From MW

> so embarrassing, awkward, or upsetting as to cause one to cringe

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cringeworthy

Comment: I would accept this as an answer if I could accept two answers.

Comment: IMO this word better fits what the OP is looking for, although it's slightly informal.

Comment: Surprisingly this dates only from 1972. OED has fab etymology: "Popularized by the name of the character Cuthbert Cringeworthy, the obsequious, assiduous schoolboy ‘swot’ in The Bash Street Kids (a strip in the British children's comic Beano).", "[1972   Beano 1 Apr. 10   ‘This is our new little chum Cuthbert Cringeworthy.’ ‘Greetings, ugly pupils!’]" See: http://www.beano.com/

Comment: Cringe.  The word is "Cringe".

Comment: You might say the action was cringeworthy.  I don't see how you could say it gave you a 'cringeworthy' feeling to watch though, that doesn't sound natural.

Comment: When you see something cringeworthy, you cringe. It's the cringeworthiness of the cringeworthy thing which makes you cringe.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers offer good, technically-correct answers, but I wouldn't use any of those in everyday conversation to express the exact idea you want. There is a phrase, however, I find is used quite often in normal conversation: *to feel embarrassed for someone*, i.e. when someone makes a fool of themselves (especially during a public performance or appearance) you *feel embarrassed for them*.

It might mean you "feel the embarrassment they are or should be feeling", in other words a sort of *empathetic embarrassment*. Or it might have a more personal meaning: you "feel embarrassed for being a member of the same species".

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can imagine, there isn't such a word in the English language, but there are a few words that could be made to fit with that idea.

*Empathize* means sympathizing with another person's unfortunate circumstances. Though *empathizing* with a person doesn't exactly have to do with that person's ineptitude, you can elaborate on the idea easily enough to make it clear. *Empathize* means to put yourself in another person's shoes or to feel as another person feels.

*Pity* is another word that is commonly understood but also commonly forgotten. Unfortunately the word *pity* in modern times has taken on a sort of high and mighty tone that discourages its use, but it means almost exactly what you're trying to express: pity for the person for the embarrassment he or she has brought upon him- or herself.

I'm quite positive there are others, but I have a migraine. :) Hope these help!

Comment: I don't think "empathize" works as that means sharing the feelings of the other and that is not happening here - they are unaware that they are there to be laughed at and that they are obliging.

Comment: "As far as I can imagine, there isn't..." is a statement really only about your imagination, isn't it?

Comment: That's not what empathize means. You defined Sympathize, instead. Empathize means you've actually been in their shoes/experienced what they are experiencing. Sympathize means you just feel for them because you can imagine what they're going through.

Comment: @TylerH Sorry, you're mistaken. Empathize and sympathize have fairly similar meanings. Empathy describes an ability to feel as another person feels. Sympathy describes a sort of vicarious sharing of experience (or rather the effects of an experience). Of course, sympathy in particular has many different definitions, but the point is both empathize and sympathize could be used here. Sympathize might come off as too strong a word, though, since that's exactly the word that's commonly used to offer condolences on the death of a loved one.

Comment: No, you are mistaken. Sympathize means you have not experienced something personally but you can *understand* someone's pain, discomfort, sadness, et cetera. Empathize specifically means that you have **personal experience** with something. It's a difference between knowing something in theory and having done it in practice.

Comment: TylerH is right. Empathize does not mean sympathizing. Empathize means having empathy, which is having the same feeling as someone else. Sympathizing means having sympathy, which is feeling badly *for* someone else without feeling what they feel yourself. Empathy is more powerful in my opinion. And, neither of these define what the OP was looking for; quite the opposite, in fact!

Comment: See Merriam-Webster's definitions for [empathize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empathize) and [sympathize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sympathize). Additionally, consider the etymology of [each](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=empathy&searchmode=none) [words](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sympathy&searchmode=none).