# Embarrassment/awkward feeling/moment while watching movie scene as if you are on the spot

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms

My younger brother was watching this movie the other day called Take Me Home Tonight (2011). and I walked in. There was this scene where Topher Grace and his mate with his twin sister as come to a party "Reunion" one. And this high-school crush was in and they all have a reuniting conversation while Topher Grace is till away wanting in the first place to meet this girl and shown trying too hard to fit in. As the scene progress, it is bizarrely awkward moment to the point of feeling embarrassment for the movie audience (to this point that my brother wanted to pause and fast forward that scene) and  without saying anything to him I felt like it too.(as if you don't have the guts to watch the mortifying scene).

I want to know what is the expression, phrase or idiom for this feeling where you want to watch the movie but too embarrass to watch the scene as if you are on the spot instead of Topher Grace.

Comment: Possible duplicate: "[What word means “the feeling of discomfort caused by watching people's ineptitude”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207397)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of [vicarious embarrassment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicarious_embarrassment). As far as I'm aware there is no one-word term for it, unless you want to go German and call it "fremdscham" (as a counterpoint to "schadenfreude").